# Word/phrase for "created by someone with poor imagination"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase for "created by someone with poor imagination"?

(Preferably not very offensive. "Think big" is not offensive, so maybe this doesn't need to be offensive either)

Comment: Friendly warning: Single word requests are best with a sample sentence, and you can avoid down/close votes by having one. Eg "The toy was great, but the packaging was *created by someone with poor imagination*.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if there is any such single word. There might be a noun for *someone with a poor imagination*, but you would still have to say *created by a (something)*. Or is implication enough? Just as *that device was MacGyvered* might imply it was created by someone with great imagination, would you accept *that device was bungled*? Or does *bungled* not sufficiently imply imagination (or even creation)?

Comment: (Frustratingly) unsophisticated/unimaginative?

Comment: "Half-baked" comes to mind but it's a stretch.

Comment: @Alex_ander I agree with "unimaginative" but would also suggest "uninspired" as a possibility.

Comment: @BoldBen should have been an answer.

Comment: @MaxB Thanks fot the vote of confidence, I just couldn't see how to turn it into a proper, full, answer or to recognise Alexander's suggestion properly in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **[underwhelming](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/underwhelming)**. From the Cambridge Dictionary:

> not causing someone to feel any excitement or admiration:
>
> *The food was good but unfortunately we found the rest of the experience distinctly underwhelming.*

Answer (score 1):

A common adjective used currently would be **generic**.

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generic) - **generic**:

> C. having no particularly distinctive quality or application.

Perhaps more pointedly, from [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Generic),  **generic**:

> To be so basic you can't even be basic anymore you become generic.